# Error with Hibernate:Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: java, hibernate

Here, I create Session:

```
public class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateSessionFactoryUtil() { }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error!" + e);
            }
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

MyUser:

```
@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String position;
    private int department;

    public User(){}

    public User(String lastName, String firstName, String position, int department) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;`
        this.position = position;
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

In `DAOImpl`, at the line where I initialize the session, I got an error:

```
public void save(final Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        logger.error("**DAO - save* EMPTY OBJ");
        return;
    }

    Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(o);
    tx1.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at codebox.dao.DAOImpl.save(DAOImpl.java:50)
    at codebox.services.UserService.saveUser(UserService.java:19)
    at codebox.Application.main(Application.java:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I did not initialize the context:
For an example in main:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run (Application.class, args);
MyService myService = (MyService) context.getBean ("myService");
```

In this service, the main beans were pulled up

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is most probably caused because you did not configure the configuration object. Please add hibernate.connection.username, hibernate.connection.password, hibernate.dialect, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto and try again. If you do not set these properties then every time your session will be null. You also can check how to do this with hibernate.cfg.xml file.

For example:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "sa");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.
But I have this

Comment: <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">cj.jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codebox</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

Comment: Ok but in your code you do not set them in the Configuration object. Please can you try to link them there with:                                                    new Configuration().configure("path_to_your_file/hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: Ok now please before you use session.save(o); you must open transaction and after that you must close it with commit. Like this: Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();   session.save(o);    tx.commit(); To understand more please read this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html

Comment: This is not the case, because the error on the line:
Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
and then inside:
 sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

Comment: This is in a case where you have to manage your transactions. Please search more information about the difference between container manage transactions and Non-managed environment.

Comment: By the way I see that you do not have hibernate.connection.driver_class and hibernate.connection.url in your configuration. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">cj.jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codebox</property>
cj was proposed as a new version, since I have mysql 8

Comment: My mistake sorry.

Comment: the problem is not about transactions, maybe in hibernate properties